# Front end output of my Mathematica is extremely slow

Tags: front-end

I am using Mathematica 12, take a look at below two runs

[image]

I already using `Short` to shorten output. The first run shows `Short` is quick. But the second run without `;` takes 10 seconds to just output several numbers? Though the timing is weirdly quick.

I also tried command line `math`, there is no problem with command line mathematica.

What is wrong with my front end? Any workarounds?

---

**update**

There are already several comments now, Thank you so much. Let me summarize as below:

compare below three runs

```
RandomReal[1., 1000000] 
RandomReal[1., 1000000] // Short
RandomReal[1., 1000000] // Shallow
```

There are several weird points:

1. Without `;`, only `Shallow` is fast, the other two are equally extremely slow. With `;`, they are all fast. Considering `Shallow` and `Short` are quite similar, this is really weird.
2. Define `menq[expr_]:=ByteCount[expr]/1024/1024.` and apply `menq` on three expression all gives `7.62958`, so output size is not a key factor here.
3. Bob Hanlon reported that macOS does not suffer from this problem. So only windows and linux suffer.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behavior that you see. Both lines execute and display quickly. I have v12 with macOS 10.15.1

Comment: I get same behavior. But I think it is due to the display part is getting gets counted in the timing. when ";" is missing. Same thing happens like this `AbsoluteTiming[Short[RandomReal[1., 100000]]]` vs. `AbsoluteTiming[Short[RandomReal[1., 100000]];]` This could be a bug, since real time shows the same, but it is not actually the same. First case is much slower in real time. V12 on windows 10.

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks for reporting. But I also tested on ubuntu with mathematica 11, same problem.

Comment: @Nasser I just found `Short` doesn't actually shorten results! `(RandomReal[1., 1000000] // Short // ByteCount)/1024/1024.` shows 7.62MB. But why is that? This is not what I expect from a `Short` result

Comment: @BobHanlon Could you ByteCount in your Mathematica?

Comment: `(RandomReal[1., 1000000] // Short // ByteCount)/1024/
  1024. // AbsoluteTiming` evaluated to `{0.008783, 7.62958}` with no appreciable delay

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks for testing.

Comment: possibly related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/209558/why-does-mathematica-consume-so-much-memory-when-reading-binary-data
Displaying the output not only takes longer, it also consumes a whole lot more memory.

Comment: Perhaps Shallow works for you, that is much much faster than Short, but functions slightly differently…

Comment: @SHuisman banone Thank you for comments, I have updated my post.

Comment: I'm inclined to write an answer, but I'm currently still at work on macOS and I want to be sure what I'm writing down. Can you test two things: First, evaluate `a = RandomReal[1., 100000] // Short;`. This should be instantaneous. What happens if you then evaluate `a`? Second: Evaluate `ToBoxes[RandomReal[1., 1000000] // Short, StandardForm]` and after that `DisplayForm[%]`. Same question: Is there a large difference between how long this takes?

Comment: @halirutan Hi, halirutan, Thank you for help. I tested it for 100000. Evaluate `a` is almost as slow as `ToBoxes[RandomReal[1., 1000000] // Short`(took about 10secs on my computer). But `DisplayForm[%]` is instantaneous.

Answer (score 8):

[`Short`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Short) is a formatting wrapper, so that it affects box generation. Basically, I think [`Short`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Short) creates the full boxes for the expression, and then it elides various pieces so that the output is shorter. Creating the full boxes is time consuming:

```
ToBoxes[RandomReal[1, 10^6]]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {2.38522, Null}

Creating the [`Short`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Short) version of the full boxes should have about the same timing:

```
ToBoxes[Short @ RandomReal[1, 10^6]]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {2.33828, Null}

If the output is not displayed, then the process of creating the full boxes is avoided:

```
ToBoxes[Short @ RandomReal[1, 10^6];] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.00955, "Null"}

This explains the behavior that you're seeing with regards to timing.

As for the [`Shallow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Shallow) timing, [`Shallow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Shallow) does not need to create the full boxes in order to create the [`Shallow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Shallow) version. Finally, the byte count of all expressions are about the same, because the underlying expressions are basically the same, it is only the boxes generated from the underlying expressions that are different.

Comment: Hi, Carl Woll, Thank you for answering. But why macOS doesn't have such problem?

Comment: @matheorem I use macOS and it has the same timing issue for me.

Comment: oh, then I do not know why  Bob Hanlon has no such issue, maybe a more powerful computer :)  Anyway, I still think this is not reasonable, because `RandomReal` is packed array which is easy to detect, and I think there is nothing worth to make box of. Why direct output of `RandomReal[1.,100000]` wil be such slow?